# C# setting up access to REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api

I'm trying to connect to a REST API.
Using Gitbash, everything works fine with the curl commnand:

```
curl -v -u APIKey:X -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET 'https://example.com/path'
```

When I try using C# I get:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending 
the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned 
an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

So what am I missing?
I have checked for proxy but my system has direct access.
Has any of you run through this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Show the C# code.

Comment: *Proxy Authentication Required*, your behind a proxy and your not authenticating/have access. *I have checked for proxy but my system has direct access* that error suggest otherwise. Contact your network support

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the issue is what is the difference between Gitbash and C#? And one of the possible answer is Gitbash is bypassing the proxy authentication. So, how can we bypass proxy authentication in C#?